# Devise is losing my current_user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise

I am trying to use Devise to implement my own authentication mechanism according to a legacy api. I am using the technique outlined at http://4trabes.com/2012/10/31/remote-authentication-with-devise/

For some reason Devise is losing the object that my custom authentication module returns.

Here is the object that my remote_authentication method returns

```
#<User:0xb65033d4 @id="MMS", @password="password", @name="MMS", @acl="YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN">
```

and here is the value passed to serialize_into_session:

```
#<User:0xb66c6be4 @id=nil, @password=nil, @name=nil, @acl=nil>
```

At this point of course, the jig is up.

Does anyone have any idea as to why this takes place and how to fix it?

Peter

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: No, I never got this resolved. Sorry.